# How do I switch between QWERTY and QWERTZ keyboard layouts of the Samsung Keyboard on Lollipop Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: samsung, keyboard

I come from English background and strongly prefer QWERTY keyboards. I also write Czech often and have installed it (instead of just typing Czech with English keyboard) to get Czech autocompletion/correction but it comes with QWERTZ layout. Is there a way to switch it to QWERTY (for example it can be done easily on all major PC platforms) or to remove the Czech keyboard while keeping Czech autocompletion dictionary?

Comment: Ah, maybe try http://www.wikihow.tech/Change-the-Language-in-Android I can't verify for the autocomplete options, but this post here seems to back it up.
http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/251675-adding-second-dictionary-spell-check.html